Existence of an immersed double torus with an order-$8$ symmetry
In this answer I gave an embedding of $K_8$ into the double torus with $C_4$ symmetry. Its dual – a map of $8$ mutually adjacent regions on the same surface, with all regions topological discs, is shown below. (Opposite circles are joined by handles.)

A double torus supporting this graph in Euclidean $3$-space can only be an immersion, not an embedding, because the two handles must intersect. So I am willing to tolerate immersions in what follows.
I initially thought that $C_4$ was the highest symmetry attainable by minimal-genus rotation systems of $K_8$, but then I ran a search and found that all such systems actually have $C_8$ symmetry, at least abstractly. Here is one such system, symmetric under $(01234567)$:
0 => 2 6 1 4 5 7 3
1 => 7 3 4 0 6 5 2
2 => 4 0 3 6 7 1 5
3 => 1 5 6 2 0 7 4
4 => 6 2 5 0 1 3 7
5 => 3 7 0 4 2 1 6
6 => 0 4 7 2 5 3 1
7 => 5 1 2 6 4 3 0

Now I want to build an immersed double torus, and on it draw the rotation system above, such that the surface's and rotation system's $C_8$ symmetries coincide. The dual map below almost satisfies my conditions, but is not immersed – it has one cusp for each vertex/region:

Is there a double torus immersed (no cusps) in Euclidean $3$-space with a symmetry of order $8$?
